# Question about working on multiple changes to a github repo at once

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration

I am working on my first large project being hosted on github for my new company. I have added requested functionality, pushed it, and opened a PR, and now I want to continue working on another feature without waiting for the PR to be merged, while still avoiding conflicts.

The new feature will require access to code in the current PR I've made. Do I keep working on this branch until the PR is merged, and then just switch all of the code between now and then to ANOTHER branch at that point? Or do I need to checkout back to master (which currently doesn't have the code I'll need access to) and just do what I can until the PR is merged? I'm not sure what the most conflict free way is to go about continuing to work while waiting for PR's to be merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your branch with PR is called `newFeature`.

The easiest way to do what you want is to create another branch, branching off `newFeature`, so you need to execute:

```
git checkout newFeature
git checkout -b extendedFeature
```

This way you will have new branch, with all the code you need :)

Comment: See I've been told that branching off an existing branch can get real messy when the existing one gets pulled. Is that all just hoopla and I should be good to do just that?

Comment: @JoshBangle yes, you are safe to do that